# Install packages online from MiKTeX console

Tags: miktex, installing, miktex-update

I tried installing a package automatically from the MiKTeX console, but it keeps showing this error message

```
a connection to mirrors.hit.edu.cn could not be established
```

What is the solution to this problem as manual installation is hectic?

Comment: Try another mirror.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not working because of strict corporate firewall policy, etc., but you can download manually the package archive file from a mirror (usually `packagename.tar.lzma`, and they could be found on the next path on mirrors: `/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/`), you can do the next (manual package installation):

1. Unpack the package archive somewhere. usually there is a `texmf` directory in it with one or more of the next subdirectories: `doc`, `source`, `tex`, `tpm`.
2. Copy these subdirectories to your systems MikTex installations proper subdirectory. The proper subdirectory where you can find the aforementioned 4 subdirectories. It can be `texmfs\install\`, but this maybe varies from system to system.
3. In order to refresh MikteX's file database you have to issue the next command in the command line: `initexmf --update-fndb`.

Answer (score 0):

Unpack the package archive somewhere. usually there is a texmf directory in it with one or more of the next subdirectories: doc, source, tex, tpm.